# Error 500 Rails + Passenger + Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ubuntu-14.04, passenger

I've configure Apache 2.4.1 + Ruby on Rails using passenger on Ubuntu 14.04, but when I try to access my application I get a 500 error... the last log of apache and my VirtualHost config are here:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f27e04d8ed014554c7b64bb54321a9d7

Comment: Which version of Passenger are you running?

Comment: Could be related to [this issue](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1362) which has been fixed as of Passenger 4.0.58

Comment: I am using the lattest version of passenger